# How Can I use Null Lambda in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I want to declare a function like this:

```
template <typename Lambda>
int foo(Lambda bar) {
    if(/* check bar is null lambda */)
        return -1;
    else
        return bar(3);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << foo([](int a)->int{return a + 3;}) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(NULL_LAMBDA) << std::endl;
}
```

Then, how can I declare the `NULL_LAMBDA` and the condition checking passed lambda function whether is null?

Comment: What do you mean by "null lambda"?

Comment: Can you use `std::optional` or the equivalent from another library?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can add a dedicated specialization:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename Lambda> int
foo(Lambda bar)
{
    return(bar(3));
}

template<> int
foo<::std::nullptr_t>(::std::nullptr_t)
{
    return(-1);
}

int main()
{
    ::std::cout << foo([] (int a) -> int {return(a + 3);}) << ::std::endl;
    ::std::cout << foo(nullptr) << ::std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Is there a benefit to a template specialization vs. a non-template overload that takes `nullptr_t` ?

Comment: @LWimsey Having template specialization would make it possible to call correct `foo` when template arguments are explicitly provided.

Comment: Please don't use specialization here. It adds nothing over just having a normal overload and can only lead to problems if you add a different overload.

Answer (score 9):

In this particular case, you can just define your null closure as one that always returns `-1`:

```
template <typename Lambda>
int foo(Lambda bar) {
    return bar(3);
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    auto const NULL_LAMBDA = [](int){ return -1; };
    std::cout << foo([](int a) {return a + 3;}) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(NULL_LAMBDA) << std::endl;
}
```

The likelihood is that if you're selecting *at run-time* which implementation to pass, then you're much better off type-erasing it with `std::function` rather than instantiating templates.  And a `std::function` is permitted to be *empty* - it can be assigned from and compared against a null pointer.

---

If you know *at compilation time* that some call sites will always pass the 'null' lambda, then you can specialise the implementation appropriately.  Obvious options include overloading `foo()` with a version that doesn't take the `bar` argument, or specializing it with a different implementation when `bar` is not a callable.

If much of `foo()` is common to both kinds of invocation (perhaps it has a lot of side effects, and `bar()` is provided as a callback?), then you might be able to conditionalise the optional part using `std::is_same<>`.  This requires `if constexpr`, as the lambda is not callable as `bar(3)`:

```
static auto const NULL_LAMBDA = nullptr;

#include <type_traits>
template <typename Lambda>
int foo(Lambda bar) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same<decltype(bar), std::nullptr_t>::value)
        return -1;
    else
        return bar(3);
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << foo([](int a) {return a + 3;}) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo(NULL_LAMBDA) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas are a category of types, not a type.

We can do this:

```
struct null_callable_t{
  template<class...Ts>
  constexpr void operator()(Ts&&...)const{}
  explicit constexpr operator bool()const{return false;}
  constexpr null_callable_t() {}
  friend constexpr bool operator==(::std::nullptr_t, null_callable_t ){ return true; }
  friend constexpr bool operator==(null_callable_t, ::std::nullptr_t ){ return true; }
  friend constexpr bool operator!=(::std::nullptr_t, null_callable_t ){ return false; }
  friend constexpr bool operator!=(null_callable_t, ::std::nullptr_t ){ return false; }
};

constexpr null_callable_t null_callable{};
```

Now our code becomes:

```
template <typename Lambda>
int foo(Lambda bar) {
  if(!bar)
    return -1;
  else
    return bar(3);
}
```

which is pretty slick:

```
std::cout << foo([](int a) {return a + 3;}) << std::endl;
std::cout << foo(null_callable) << std::endl;
```

however, my personal favorite method to solve this is to write `function_view`.

It wraps a pointer and an action up in a non-allocating thing a bit like std function.  Compilers are pretty good at inlining simple function pointers, so overhead remains low if you make the method inline.

Comment: "*however, my personal favorite method to solve this is to write function_view.*" You mean [`std::function_ref`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p0792r6.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Note in C++17 we can write this like...

```
template<typename Lambda>
int foo(Lambda bar)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Lambda>, std::nullptr_t>)
        return -1;
    else if constexpr (std::is_convertable_v<Lambda, bool>)
    {
        if (bar)
            return bar(3);
        else
            return -1;
    }
    else
        return bar(3);
}
```

I suppose in C++20 we can define a concept that std::invocable (concepts header) or nulltpr_t to constrain Lambda by.